Claymation series about a group of aliens
This series aired on Australia's ABC Channel quite some time ago, getting the feeling it was around the 1990's back when i was in primary school (though it could be as late as 2002 as memories of my first few years of high school are mixing with primary school)
In the first episode these 2 small cute looking aliens, a male and a female, are building a tower out of junk they find, i remember the planet being desolate. their goal was i think to try and get home.
These are these 2 other aliens. one wore green and i seem to remember a green helmet like that of Marvin the Martian and he never took it off even when he came out of the shower, the other in my vague memories seems to remind me of an Ood from Doctor Who appearance wise (though this may be incorrect). i don't remember that caused it but these 2 aliens end up trying to take something from this junk tower. they drag it out from the bottom with a vehicle causing the tower to begin to collapse with the cute male alien still at the very top. when the tower falls down the cute female alien thinks her friend is dead but the cute male alien calls out to her from above sitting on this floating disk. this disk end up turning into a space ship and the 4 aliens leave the planet together.
I remember that the alien who reminds me of an Ood has some for water, i don't remember if it's fear or an instant trigger of sadness but it is revealed to be a result of a truma having been born in a tank and separated from his mother.
the four aliens end up crashing on this other planet where there is this huge library where another alien, female, is who is the curator of it and allows them to stay where they help out around the place. one task i remember was that the cute male alien goes to this dam which is apparently blocked while the Ood alien forces his green helmet friend to unblock it when the cute male alien leave to clear the blockage with a tiny toothbrush (the pipe for the water dwarfs the green helmet guy). 
the green helmet guy complains about some much that seems to be leaking from the opening thinking it's the cause but the real cause was this giant fish blocking it from the other side. the cute male alien uses the toothbrush to tickle the fish to make it move which ofcause, now the pipe is unblocked, the green helmet guy is caught in the torrent of water that shoots out.
i remember someone asking the cute male alien how he was able to clean such a huge pipe with such a tiny brush and the cute male alien cleverly replies

it's not the size it matters but how you use it

as i have already mentioned i seem to remember this to be claymation but i get the feeling it's a lower quality that than of Wallace and Grommet

Sounds like Plasmo.

Australian children's science fiction claymation TV series that consisted of a half-hour short film ("Happy Hatchday to Plasmo") made in 1989 followed by thirteen 5-minute episodes made in 1996

It was about four aliens, one of which always had a green helmet on and another that looked like Ood. In the first episode, Plasmo and his female friend build a tower out of junk to try and reach the moon. Here it is:




Ahhh yes that's it. thank you
